# how to remove previous result list immediately when updating recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

here is the short video of my problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/108Tk9rmJtF3Ir7Nj9hheW2JkvlqXggcj/view

so, I have a vertical recycler view that can be refreshed when the tab layout is tapped.

If I tap the first index of the tab, it will fetch some data from the server and populate the adapter and recycler view. but if I tap the second index, the data from server is actually empty.

here is the problem...

as you can see from the short video above. when I tap the second tab (from previously in the first tab), it still shows the list from the first tab appears for a second before eventually show an empty recycler view.

I want to make after the loading the data from server, that previous result will not show, and it should immediately show the result as per the tab selected.

I am using `ListAdapter` and using `submitList()` to update the data

here is the adapter I use:

```
class GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter(val mContext: Context): ListAdapter<Event, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    lateinit var mOnEventKMListener : OnEventKMListener

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnEventKMListener) {
        mOnEventKMListener = listener
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_general_event, parent, false)
        return GeneralEventViewHolder(itemView, mOnEventKMListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val currentEvent = getItem(position)
        val generalEventViewHolder = holder as GeneralEventViewHolder

        Glide.with(mContext).load(currentEvent.thumbnailDownloadPath)
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(25, 3)))
            .into(generalEventViewHolder.blurThumbnailImageView)

        Glide.with(mContext).load(currentEvent.thumbnailDownloadPath).into(generalEventViewHolder.thumbnailImageView)


        generalEventViewHolder.eventNameTextView.text = currentEvent.title
        generalEventViewHolder.eventVenueTextView.text = currentEvent.venue
        generalEventViewHolder.eventDateTimeTextView.text = DateTimeService.changeDateToString("EEEE, d MMMM. HH:mm zzz",currentEvent.dateTimeStart)

    }


    companion object {

        private val DIFF_CALLBACK = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Event>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Event, newItem: Event): Boolean {
                return oldItem.eventID == newItem.eventID
            }

            override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Event, newItem: Event): Boolean {
                return oldItem == newItem
            }


        }
    }


}
```

and here is the simplified my fragment class:

```
class SearchResultFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var titleTextView: TextView
    lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar
    lateinit var fragmentView : View
    lateinit var tabLayout : TabLayout
    lateinit var recyclerView : RecyclerView

    lateinit var mContext : Context
    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity
    lateinit var eventAdapter : GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter

    private var eventList = ArrayList<Event>()
    private var selectedEventType = EventType.kajianUmum
    private var selectedCity = City.defaultCityName
    private var selectedTime = EventTimeUserSelection.Weekend
    lateinit var userData : User

    private var startingDate = Date()
    private var endingDate = Date()

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_result, container, false)

        setUpSafeArg()
        setUpViewsDeclaration()
        setUpListeners()
        updateUI()
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        initRecyclerView()
        searchEvents()




        return fragmentView
    }



    private fun setUpViewsDeclaration() {
        titleTextView = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.destination_label_text_view)
        progressBar = mActivity.progressBar_main_activity
        recyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_search_result)
        tabLayout = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_time_search_result)

    }



    private fun setUpListeners() {

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

                selectedTime = when(tab?.position ?: 0) {
                    0 -> EventTimeUserSelection.All
                    1 -> EventTimeUserSelection.Today
                    2 -> EventTimeUserSelection.Tomorrow
                    3 -> EventTimeUserSelection.Weekend
                    4 -> EventTimeUserSelection.ThisWeek
                    5 -> EventTimeUserSelection.NextWeek
                    else -> EventTimeUserSelection.All
                }

                searchEvents()


            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {

            }


        })

    }


    private fun initRecyclerView() {

        eventAdapter = GeneralEventRecyclerViewAdapter(mContext)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false)
        recyclerView.adapter = eventAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager


        eventAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object: OnEventKMListener {

            override fun eventKMClicked(position: Int) {
                val selectedEvent = eventList[position]
                val eventDetailDestination = SearchResultFragmentDirections.actionGlobalDestinationEventDetail(selectedEvent)
                Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(eventDetailDestination)
            }

        })




    }

    private fun searchEvents() {

        setStartingAndEndingDateForSearching()
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE


        FirestoreKMClient.getFreeEvents(startingDate,endingDate,selectedCity,selectedEventType.getEventTypeInString(),10) { errorMessage, events ->


            errorMessage?.let {
                mActivity.toast(it)
            } ?: run {

                val theEvents = events ?: ArrayList()
                eventList = theEvents
                eventAdapter.submitList(eventList)
            }

            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE


        }


    }


}
```

Java is ok

Comment: Can you show your code where you are binding the list with adapter?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good in kotlin but the my logic might work;

upon reading your code;

i guess you can try to set your adapter into null first so that it will clear all previous data that is been fetch on your first tab.

> eventAdapter.submitList(null)

you can try to put it here :

```
 private fun searchEvents() {

        setStartingAndEndingDateForSearching()
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
        eventAdapter.submitList(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to clear the list on a time of calling your data from database.

Try setting up empty list before call of new data i.e. In `searchEvents()` function below this line `recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE`.

```
recyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
eventList = arrayOf< Event>()
eventAdapter.submitList(eventList)
```